# Is there a Runescape Grand Exchange feature which shows the Volume in which items are traded?

Tags: runescape

I'm looking for something that could tell me how much of an item is traded, rather than just the price. This is useful to me for figuring out which items to buy/make/harvest. Basically, I'd like to avoid the problem I keep having of finding something worth more than the material cost, but never sell (for example, making prayer urns). I should also mention that I'm a free to play member, though I'm not sure if that matters at all.

Currently, I'm looking at the price fluctuations of an item over the past 30 days, and making the assumption that items which fluctuate more wildly are bought in higher volume than those which aren't. However, this is not always accurate.

As an example, I'm looking for something where I could type in "Bronze Bar" and be told, for example, "246 Bronze Bars were bought yesterday. 3,021 have been bought in the past week. 11,204 have been bought in the last month."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jagex does not seem to release information in general about the trade volume of every item in the game, but as Warface pointed out, Jagex releases some of the statistics about the [top 100 most traded items](http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/g=runescape/top100.ws?list=0&scale=0) for a given time period. This shows for a time period of 7, 30, 90, or 180 days a few trade volume statistics for the 100 most traded items during that period of time.

Answer (score 1):

on the main site under one of the drop donw options-> grand exchange should be a graph for this, but it's been half a year since i played so it might not be correct.

Comment: I know the price graph is there, but I'm looking for a volume graph.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's a top 100 of the most items traded in the game:

http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/g=runescape/top100.ws?list=0&scale=0